# CSS - extra height being given to div? Huge space between footer and container

Tags: html, css

I am in the process of creating a website and I am having a problem -

There is a huge space between my footer and the rest of my content. I have a container which holds all of my content, including my footer, however there is a separate div holding the content within that container. The container div does not have a height set to it, as it is supposed to expand with the content.

CSS for container:

```
.middle-container {
margin:0 auto;
margin-bottom:40px;
width:980px;
background-color:hsla(90,10%,20%,1);
padding-top:15px;
}
```

My footer does not contain any code which should affect this, as when I remove this completely, the extra height is still there. I've tried everything I can think of however I'm not extremely advanced in CSS, still learning. I would post my entire CSS contents here however it's a large file as it has code for multiple pages, and is for a personal site.

If you have any ideas or if I'm missing anything anything obvious, please let me know.

Also if I add a height of 400px to the container, it still does not reduce the space - it just removed the background colour of it and my footer div is still 500/600px below the content.

Thanks

Comment: also, can you give more HTML/CSS? The quoted code is only part of the picture

Comment: You should really create a JsFiddle, this will allow other users to still see the problem and solution even after it has been fixed.

Comment: What is the code for your footer?

Comment: ALso is there any content inside .middle-container?

Comment: Jsfiddle ??? yaaar make it easy

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-bottom:40px;` and that should get rid of the gap.

Answer (score 0):

A small note your CSS should look like:

```
.middle-container{
 margin:0 auto 40px;
 width:980px;
 background-color:hsla(90,10%,20%,1);
 padding-top:15px;
}
```